# IE9 is not showing ANY bootstrap based site

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue.  We are working on redoing our site with a bootstrap theme.
Works great on Chrome Firefox and safari but the site does not load on IE9.  NO site loads on IE9 not even the main boostrap site.

I have restored IE8 and that seemed to work but looks like my computer updated to IE9 today and nothing is coming up.  Not sure what is causing this issue but we do not want to go forward with all this work if there is an issue with Bootstrap and IE9.
I have to assume it is something with my computer .  IF anyone has any suggestion we are all ears here.
Thanks
Matt

Comment: Mine IE9 pretty well show http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. Address is correct?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall (that might be blocking anything with twitter in its url)?

Comment: no firewall and the url address is correct.

Comment: Then I'm 90% sure that the problem is in the your network settings in IE. Try to install back IE9 with the default settings

Answer (score 0):

For me it works without the quirksmode of the ie. With this mode the site wasnot show correctly, but with the doktype ie9 or ie8 it works very well. If you add the right doctype it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

for example.

And you can add additional meta info

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

its just a example, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (IE9, Win764-bit, Yii and Abound Theme using Bootstrap):

Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Added in Head tag:

```
<head>
...
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has an issue with rendering certain Type 1 fonts.

Bootstrap uses Helvetica in their CSS:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

See this article for more details:
http://bobbyjoneswebdesign.blogspot.ca/2011/12/internet-explorer-9-type-1-font-bug.html